# Displaying XML file contents in Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

i have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CRM>
  <Unit ID="1" Name="آذربایجان شرقی">
    <city ID="1">آذرشهر </city>
    <city ID="2">اسکو  </city>
    <city ID="3">اهر  </city>
    <city ID="12">کلیبر </city>
    <city ID="13">مراغه </city>
    <city ID="14">مرند </city>
    <city ID="15">ملکان </city>
    <city ID="16">ملکان </city>
    <city ID="17">میانه </city>
    <city ID="18">ورزقان </city>
    <city ID="19">هریس </city>
    <city ID="20">هشترود</city>
  </Unit>

  <Unit  ID="2"  Name="آذربایجان غربی">
    <city ID="1">ارومیه </city>
    <city ID="2">اشنویه </city>
    <city ID="3">بوکان </city>
    <city ID="4">پیرانشهر </city>
    <city ID="5">تکاب </city>
    <city ID="6">چالدران </city>
  </Unit>

  <Unit ID="3" Name="اردبیل">
    <city ID="1">اردبیل </city>
    <city ID="2">بیله‌سوار </city>
  </Unit>

  <Unit ID="4" Name="اصفهان">
    <city ID="1">آران و بیدگل</city>
    <city ID="2">اردستان </city>
    <city ID="3">اصفهان </city>
    <city ID="4">برخوار و میمه</city>
    <city ID="5">تیران و کرون</city>
    <city ID="6">چادگان </city>
    <city ID="7">خمینی‌شهر </city>
    <city ID="8">خوانسار </city>
    <city ID="9">سمیرم </city>
    <city ID="10">شهرضا"</city>
    <city ID="11">سمیرم سفلی"</city>
    <city ID="12">فریدن"</city>
  </Unit>
</CRM>
```

I'm showing list name unit in `html.dropdownlist`

I use this code:

```
List<SelectList> u = new List<SelectList>();

var locations = XDocument.Load(strXmlpath);
var query = from l in locations.Descendants("CRM") select l;

foreach (var q in query)
{
  u.Add(new SelectList(new[] {
                               new {ID   = q.Attributes("ID").FirstOrDefault(),
                                    Name = q.Attributes("Name").FirstOrDefault()
                                   }
                             },
                       "ID", "Name", 1));
}

ViewData["xml"] = new SelectList(u,"ID","Name");
```

This is in the view:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("xml",(SelectList) ViewData["xml"] )%>
```

But results in this error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a view model:

```
public class UnitViewModel
{
    public string SelectedID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Units { get; set; }
}
```

which I would populate in my controller action after parsing the XML file:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // TODO: it would be better to externalize the parsing of the XML
    // file into a separate repository class to avoid cluttering your
    // controller actions with such code which is not what they should
    // be responsible for. But for the purpose of this answer it should 
    // be enough 

    var file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/app_data"), "crm.xml");
    var model = new UnitViewModel
    {
        Units = 
            from unit in XDocument.Load(file).Document.Descendants("Unit")
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = unit.Attribute("ID").Value,
                Text = unit.Attribute("Name").Value
            }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in my strongly typed view I would generate the dropdownlist based on this view model:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedID,
    new SelectList(Model.Units, "Value", "Text")
) %>
```

Comment: tanx . but if want use from ViewDate shoud do? for example  ViewData["xml"] =model;

Comment: @user764499, personally I hate `ViewData`. I never use it and I would never recommend it to anyone. I always prefer using strongly typed view models.

Comment: but my page Includes Many parts for example list unit from xml file with display in dropdoewnlist and list activity from other xml file with display in dropdownlist and textboxes for enter details customer what should i do?

Comment: @user764499, in this case you define another view model which will contain as properties all the necessary parts and one of its properties will be the model I showed in my example. Then you will pass this new view model to your view and so it will have access to everything.

Answer (score 0):

So I used this topic and some others to figure out the fix i needed for my country dropdownlist. i figured it might help people in the future.

This works like a charm might not be the cleanest solution but hey it works

```
        var file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/xml"), "countries.xml"); 
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(file);
        XmlNodeList countryList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Country");

        List<SelectListItem> countries = new List<SelectListItem>(); 

        foreach (XmlNode country in countryList) 
        { 
            string name = country.ChildNodes[0].InnerText; 
            string code = country.ChildNodes[1].InnerText; 


            countries.Add(new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = name, 
                Value = code 
            }); 
        }

        ViewBag.country = new SelectList(countries, "Value", "Text");

        return View();
```